Tamil font missing

I recently installed Ubuntu 24.10.
Whats App, Chrome and Microsoft Edge browsers are not reading the Tamil font properly, some characters square
How to fix this issue?

Have you installed Tamil language support?

Try sudo apt install fonts-noto-core

Did nothing change after installing fonts-noto-core?
