My language Tamil characters are not getting displayed in browsers. They are displayed as empty boxes
I was recently browsing some websites in my native language, and found that some characters were not displayed in the web browser. I tried with many browsers and all of them are same. In Windows there are no issues. How can I fix this? Due to this I need to switch to Windows every time to consume native language content.

EDIT 1: I just tried in firefox and the websites are loading fine. The issue occurs only in chromium based browsers.

possibly related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1533102/tamil-font-missing

This question is similar to: Tamil typing help. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@graham Thanks. The first link you provided is similar question but comments on the post did not resolve the issue. The second link is related to typing in Tamil Tamil with keyboard input which is not related to the issue I'm facing.

@graham In firefox the characters are shown properly. Only in chromium based browsers (I checked in Chrome/Brave/Opera) this is happening.

then try some of the options in the comments on this question
